# reCAPTCHA on Visualforce pgage

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputfield, form, google

I've been looking for a way to implement reCAPTCHA or any type of CAPTCHA on a Visualforce form. It appears that reCAPTCHA has been updated since this posted 
[Adding CAPTCHA to Force.com sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites). Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to properly implement the updated reCAPTCHA with a VF page? I can't seem to find much information on it.

Comment: Could you figure this out?

Comment: No I have not figured this out

Comment: I was able to achieve it yesterday after lot of brain wrenching .. will post an answer soon

Comment: I haven't tested this but it could solve this issues: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_web_to_lead_recaptcha.htm

Comment: http://poppinggums.com/2017/03/16/adding-captcha-to-force-com-sites

Answer (score 1):

- Register with Google Account for an API Key:

  Go to this link - https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

  Fill the form & Register

  You will receive ‘Site Key’ & ‘Secret Key’
- Generate Web-To-Lead form:

  Go to Setup -> Web-to-lead -> Click on ‘Create Web-to-lead form’

  [image]

  [image]

  Save & Generate.

  You will receive HTML Code.

  Copy-Paste the code in registered Domain site & Run.

(You can refer this link also - https://sfdcquery.blogspot.com/2019/01/re-captcha.html)